# Proving that there are relatively prime elements (Posa problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove that for each $n+1$  an element from the set $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,2n-1,2n\}$ there are two relatively prime elements between them

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry: I don't know what a rational prime element is.

Comment: While "rational prime" does have a meaning, I suspect you mean relatively prime.

Comment: I suspect the question is: given any $n+1$ elements of that set, prove that there must be two of them that are relatively prime.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews yes you are right I meant to say relatively prime.Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ $ Show by pigeonhole that subset has a neighboring pair $\rm\:n,\, n\!+\!1,\:$ which is coprime

Answer (score 1):

Group the $2n$ integers into $n$ sets: $\{1,2\}, \{3,4\},\cdots,\{2n-1,2n\}$. The elements in each set are coprime. Now use the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $a,b,c$ be elements in a subset $S$ of $\{1,\dotsc,2n\}$ of cardinality $n+1$. Suppose that there is a prime $p$ which divides $a$ and $b$, but not $c$. If another prime $q$ divides $c$ but not $a$ or $b$ you are done. Otherwise in a similar way you can prove that there is a prime $r$ which divides every element in $S$...